# discord.py warning system checking warnings

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm still making a warning system but in the process I am having this issue with the embed showing the warning multiple times. Shown in the image provided.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks4Gm.png I'm not sure what could be causing this but I think it might be the for loop I made?

```
@client.hybrid_command(name = "warnings", with_app_command=True, description="View the warnings of a member", aliases=["punishments"])
async def warnings(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.reply("A Member is required")
    else:
        check = warndb.warn_logs.find_one({"user_id": member.id})
        if check is None:
            await ctx.reply("This user has no warns")
        else:
            reason = check["reason"]
            moderator_id = check["moderator_id"]
            embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title=f"{member.name}'s warnings")
            for w in check:
                embed.add_field(name=f"{reason}", value=f"<@{moderator_id}>", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

There is no error and it works fine it just shows the warning(s) multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You query with `find_one` so there is no point in looping over `check`.

I would try to just remove the line `for w in check:`.

If it's suppose to be an array(change to find_all), maybe you manually adding data to the table when testing and it's displaying all previous warns you've added.

Comment: `NoneType: None
'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'find_all' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`

I get this error when changing find_one to find_all

Comment: My bad, it's ```warndb.find({"user_id": member.id})``` .

Comment: It's not solving the problem.

try to print ```check``` in the line before the loop, maybe it'll help you understand..

Paste the output here if you didn't solve it..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally. The issue is you need to turn the `check = warndb.warn_logs.find_one({"user_id": member.id})` into a list by doing `check = list(warndb.warn_logs.find_one({"user_id": member.id}))`. Once you do that you should use the `.get()` function to get the values of the keys

In this case:

```
for w in check:
    reason = w.get('reason')
    moderatorid = w.get('moderator_id')
    guildid = w.get('guild_id')
    caseid = w.get('_id')
    embed.add_field(name=f"Case ID: {caseid}—Reason: {reason}", value=f"<@{moderatorid}>", inline=False)
```